# Website directs to page with .html after a few clicks?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website here:

www.arshak.co.uk

When you go on say, www.arshak.co.uk/about

It will work.

But on that webpage if you were to go on the contact page, the url won't have .html, but if you redirect yourself to another webpage from the webpage you are on, then the .html appears.

How to stop this?

This is my navbar code:

```
<a href="https://www.arshak.co.uk"><font color="white"><p>Home</p></font></a>
        <a href="https://www.arshak.co.uk/youtube"><font color="white"><p>My YouTube</p></font></a>
        <a href="https://www.arshak.co.uk/aims"><font color="black"><p>Personal Aims</p></font></a>
        <a href="https://www.arshak.co.uk/contact"><font color="white"><p>Contact Me</p></font></a>
        <a href="https://www.arshak.co.uk/about"><font color="white"><p>About Me</p></font></a>
```

This is my .htaccess code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Help!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "redirect yourself to another page"? Do you mean if you click on one of the links on your website? If so, what is the href attribute of that link? Does it have `.html` in it?

Comment: No; I checked. All the href attributes are not set to .html.

Comment: What do you mean by redirect yourself? When does it happen? From your .htaccess, it looks like everything should work

Comment: This sounds like it might be a caching issue - try clearing your browser cache. If you've previously been experimenting with external 301 redirects (perhaps in error) then the browser is likely to have cached these. I've browsed your site and I'm unable to reproduce this behaviour. Only if I manually type `.html` into the address bar does the `.html` appear (that in itself is another problem).